# Dump from Local Sqlite3 and Import in Heroku Production Server

Tags: django, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I have Django App on Heroku.

My local dev server is running django with Sqlite, which contains lots of data(couple of gigs) that I want to transfer to Heroku Postgre.

Heroku provides [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) import/export guide that let's one export from local POSTGRE db, create a dumpfile and import it (pg:restore) on Prod. heroku DB.

How can I generate dump file from my Sqlite db and and import in Heroku Postgre ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended moving to Postgre SQl on dev server. The link below made my life easier on moving data from Sqlite3 to Postgre.

https://racingtadpole.com/blog/django-fixtures-to-copy-database/

After this, I will pg-backup to create a dump file and populate heroku database.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't answer your question directly, but I recommend against the use of different databases in development and production. Consider reading this great [article](http://12factor.net) describing methodologies for developing apps for cloud deployment and especially this [page](http://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am moving to post-gre on dev and prod.